# Expected Value Composition

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, expected-value

I am given the following:

Let X be Poisson with parameter λ > 0. For any positive integer k, calculate
E(X(X − 1)(X − 2) × · · · × (X − k).

I know the answer is as follows: $$\sum _{n >= 0} n(n-1)(n-2)  ... λ^k e^{-λ}/n! $$

I'm a little unsure how they were able to come up with this answer from the problem statement.  I was thinking it came from the property that expected value is a linear, but am really not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just by the definition of expectation

$$E[g(X)] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty Pr(X=x) g(x) $$

here $g(x) = \prod_{i=0}^k (x-i)$.

\begin{align}
E \left[ \prod_{i=0}^k (X-i) \right] &= \sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{\exp(-\lambda)\lambda^x}{x!}\prod_{i=0}^k (x-i)
\end{align}